# How to disable built-in web server in IntelliJ IDEA for "Open in Browser" command?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA has a built-in web server in the latest releases that works when I use "Open in Browser" command for some HTML file. So, the URL looks like:

```
http://localhost:63342/file.html
```

I want to see a `file://` based URL (because the web server doesn't link sibling files in the same directory, for example), but I can't find any option to do it. So, how can I disable this web server or maybe where can I find another command to view files in the browser directly? Of course, I can click "Copy Path" and paste it to the url bar of the browser, but I'm looking for a more convenient way.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using? And the built-in server does in fact return sibling files from the same directory if you have correct relative URLs in your HTML.

Comment: I am using IDEA 14. If I am correct this feature exists from IDEA 13.

Comment: @yole Really, relative URLs are work. The problem is only with absolute URLs. Nevertheless, the question remains.

Comment: So how exactly would absolute URLs work if you opened your file via the file:/// protocol?

Comment: If I open a some file:///path/file.html with <script src="file:///path/to/script.js"> inside or <script src="/path/to/script.js"> it is work. But both of them does not work if I open http://localhost:port/file.html (the first is because of security reasons, the second does not exists under localhost).

Comment: I am interested as well

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here are the steps on how to disable the built-in web server in IntelliJ IDEA for the "Open in Browser" command:

1. Open IntelliJ IDEA.
2. Go to **File** > **Settings**.
3. In the **Settings** dialog, go to **Tools** > **Web Browsers and Preview**.
4. In the **Built-in Server** section, uncheck the **Enable** checkbox.
5. Click **OK** to save your changes.

Once you have disabled the built-in web server, the "Open in Browser" command will no longer open the file in the built-in web server. Instead, it will open the file in your default web browser.

Here are some additional things to keep in mind:

- If you have already opened a file in the built-in web server, you will need to close the file before the changes will take effect.
- If you have configured IntelliJ IDEA to open files in a specific browser, the "Open in Browser" command will still open the file in that browser, even if the built-in web server is disabled.

Comment: There is no **Built-in Server** option in my IDEA 2022.3

Comment: In my IDE, there is a option. I disabled it and work it for me.