# Why am I getting message "Built-in web server is deactivated, to activate, please use Open in Browser" from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I recently upgraded IntelliJ IDEA from version 14.1.6 to version 14.1.7 due to their [latest security update](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/). Part of the update appear to be updates to their "built-in web server", which I've never used to my knowledge.

The upgrade seems to work fine, but now on occasion while I'm working I get a notification in the upper-right corner "Built-in web server is deactivated, to activate, please use Open in Browser". I haven't yet figured out what it is that I'm doing to trigger it, I think because as I'm working I'm not looking up there, and I only see it later.

While dismissing the message works fine and I'm happily continuing to work, **I'm not sure what to turn off in order to prevent the message from showing up more.** Is there some feature I've inadvertently told it to use and there is some problem with it?

There a question here on [How to disable built-in web server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28855290/65839) but I'm not sure if that's talking about the same feature, and it's referring to a file URL whereas I'm testing my application in Tomcat using http, and as of this writing that question isn't answered either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the notification in Preferences → Appearance & Behavior → Notifications → Built-in server. Set Popup to `No popup` and deselect `Log` if you don't want a notification in the log.

While I'm not sure *why* this happens, it seems that one cause is using the built in documentation tool (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Win) / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Mac)).

Comment: This is exactly when I getting it. Any idea why and how can I fix it so I can see the documentation again?

Comment: This setting stops the "Built-in web server is deactivated…" popup from appearing, but `Ctrl+Q` still works for showing the documentation for me. Perhaps you're having a different issue?